# Expectation for n'th Markov Chain Link

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a markov chain $X_n$ and have computed $a(n)$ such that $P(X_{n+1} = X_n + 1) = a(X_n)$, $P(X_{n+1} = X_n) = 1-a(X_n)$, with no other possible values for $X_{n+1}$. I have $X_0$ so this should allow me to calculate  $E[X_n]$, but the only way I can think of doing so would be to build a transition matrix with $a(X_n)-1$ on the diagonals, $a(X_n)$ right above those entries and $0s$ everywhere else, and then raise it to the $n'th$ power, and manually calculate the expectation from the resulting distribution. The issue is that the state space is not finite, so the matrix would be infinitely large. Could someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Note that $X_n = X_0 + \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ where $Y_i$ are Bernoulli random variables with $\Pr(Y_i = 1) = a(i-1)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks sudeep, I realized I had typed my question incorrectly, I meant $a(X_n)$ not $a(n)$, the probability of $X_{n+1} = X_n + 1$ depends not on the time of the transition but on the state at which the transition occurs. Sorry for the error.

Comment: Oh I see. Do you have the specific form for $a(x)$? Maybe that might make the problem easier.

Comment: Its linear: $a(X_n) = c_1 - c_2*X_n$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are fixed for all $X_n$

Comment: Then note that $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}| X_n] = X_n + a(X_n) \implies \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}] = c_1 - (c_2 - 1)\mathbb{E}[X_n]$. You can now solve this recurrence relation using standard linear recurrence relation techniques.